# How can I reach to the image node

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I have a JSON structure like below and I cannot reach to the image node in no way. How can I do that with Volley library? Any ideas will be helpful. Thanks in advance.

```
{
  "nodes": [
    {
      "node": {
        "id": "2536",
        "title": "Die Düsseldorfer Rabbiner",
        "image": {
          "src": "how to reach here",
          "alt": "",
          "title": "© Landeshauptstadt Düsseldorf/Michael Gstettenbauer"
        },
        "body": "some text",
        "category": "Deutsch",
        "created": "1481344134",
        "url": "some text"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Code Block

```
JsonArrayRequest getRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(
            url,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject("response");
                        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("nodes");
                        for(int i = 0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++){
                            JSONObject jo = jsonArray .getJSONObject(i);
                            String name = jo.getString("category");

                            Toast.makeText(context, name, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
```

Comment: how are you parsing your json, doing it manually or using any library like - GSON.

Comment: `new JSONObject("object")` what do you think that does?

Comment: Hi Ravinder, I have added my code block. Could you please check it? I think I am doing right but it does not work.

Comment: @njzk2 sorry, I think it should be "response" should not it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
From the look of things you should  use JsonObjectRequest instead  JsonArrayRequest.

 JsonObjectRequest request=new JsonObjectRequest(url, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                    try {
                        JSONArray  array = response.getJSONArray("nodes");
                        for(int i=0;i<array.length();i++){
                            JSONObject object= array.getJSONObject(i);
                            JSONObject imageObject= object.getJSONObject("node").getJSONObject("image");
                            Toast.makeText(TestActivity.this, imageObject.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

Your Java model should match the JSON *exactly*. The base element in your JSON schema is an *object*, not an array; therefore your request should be a `JSONObjectRequest`, not a `JSONArrayRequest`:

```
JSONObjectRequest request = new JSONObjectRequest(url,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    try {
                        JSONArray nodes = response.getJSONArray("nodes");
                        for(int i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
                            JSONObject obj = nodes.getJSONObject(i);
                            JSONObject node = obj.getJSONObject("node");
                            JSONObject image = node.getJSONObject("image");
                            String title = image.getString("title");

                            Toast.makeText(context, title, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
```

As you might be able to see, this can get tedious if you have a large dataset. Which is why I highly recommend using a JSON parsing library; such as [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson), [Moshi](https://github.com/square/moshi) or [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson). There is a good tutorial on how to make a custom request with Volley to make use of these libraries in the [training documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/request-custom.html).